Can I tell Apple Photos to merge two duplicate photos that it hasn't identified as duplicates?
My family uses Apple Photos on our Macs (Sonoma) and iPhones (iOS 17) with a shared library. We have a lot of duplicate photos from before. I used the built in "Duplicates" album and its "Merge" function to remove a lot of duplicates, but there are still a bunch that Photos doesn't recognize.
Sometimes I run across two files that are obviously duplicates. I'd like to tell Photos to merge them. I can imitate this manually by deleting one of the photos, but this will remove the deleted photo from family members' albums without adding the duplicate.
Is there any way to tell Photos to merge a set of photos that it has not identified as duplicates?

I don't believe this is currently possible.  I looked for a way to do it on my Mac but couldn't find one. I'm not 100% sure, though, so I'm not adding this as an answer.
